# Microdata on Products

Tags: html, microdata

I´d want to use microdata in my site (in beta) products pages.

But I couldn´t figure out how to accomplish that, because of the fact that all prices are not shown at all, due to commercial reasons. But the Products schema requires an explicit price on page. Am I misunderstood something? May I use another schema?

Any advise on this scenario will be greatly appreciated.

Txs in adv

Ariel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What "Products schema" are you referring to? http://schema.org/Product for example does not require you to have a price, but search providers like Google or Bing might require you to list a price for your page to appear as a [product Rich Snippet](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146750) (price is required in the offer section). You might want to check if the Offer-aggregate can somehow address your need, as it only requires a lowPrice value.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts scor. 
Anyway, my goal is to get my listing into Google, so I think I should try your suggestions.